# MultiView in ASP.NET

Tags: .net, asp.net, multiview

I am using multiview with asp menu creating tabs in menu.
but by switching to different tabs.. my content on tabs remain same.
following is code

```
<asp:Menu
    ID="Menu1"
    Width="168px"
    runat="server"
    Orientation="Horizontal"
    StaticEnableDefaultPopOutImage="False"
    OnMenuItemClick="Menu1_MenuItemClick">
    <Items>
        <asp:MenuItem  Text="TAB1" Value="0"></asp:MenuItem>
        <asp:MenuItem  Text="TAB2" Value="1"></asp:MenuItem>
        <asp:MenuItem   Text="TAB3" Value="2"></asp:MenuItem>
    </Items>
</asp:Menu>
<asp:MultiView 
    ID="MultiView1"
    runat="server"
    ActiveViewIndex="0"  >
    <asp:View ID="tab1" runat="server"  >
        <table width="200" height="100" cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>
            <tr valign="top">
                <td class="TabArea" style="width: 600px">
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    TAB VIEW 1
                    INSERT YOUR CONENT IN HERE
                    CHANGE SELECTED IMAGE URL AS NECESSARY
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </asp:View>
    <asp:View ID="tab2" runat="server">
        <table width="200px" height="100px" cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>
            <tr valign="top">
                <td class="TabArea" style="width: 600px">
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    TAB VIEW 2
                    INSERT YOUR CONENT IN HERE
                    CHANGE SELECTED IMAGE URL AS NECESSARY
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </asp:View>
    <asp:View ID="tab3" runat="server">
        <table width="200px" height="100px" cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>
            <tr valign="top">
                <td class="TabArea" style="width: 600px">
                    <br />
                    <br />
                     TAB VIEW 3
                     INSERT YOUR CONENT IN HERE
                     CHANGE SELECTED IMAGE URL AS NECESSARY
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </asp:View>
</asp:MultiView>
```

by clicking on different tabs my content still shows of first tab any idea why.

You help will be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you need to handle the `OnMenuItemClick` in your code-behind:

```
protected void Menu1_MenuItemClick(object sender, MenuItemEventArgs e)
{

    string menuTab = e.MenuItem.Value;

    switch (menuTab)
    {
        case "0":
            MultiView1.SetActiveView(tab1);
            break;
        case "1":
            MultiView1.SetActiveView(tab2);
            break;
        case "2":
            MultiView1.SetActiveView(tabe);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Tim I believe that should be a `switch` for C# not a select.

Comment: @JoJo - Good catch.  Can't believe I missed that.  I've fixed the typo, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

```
     protected void menuTabs_MenuItemClick(object sender, MenuEventArgs e)
    {
        multiTabs.ActiveViewIndex = Int32.Parse(menuTabs.SelectedValue);
        if (menuTabs.Items[0].Selected == true)
        {

            menuTabs.Items[0].ImageUrl = "~/Images/wit1_over.png";
            menuTabs.Items[1].ImageUrl = "~/Images/wit2.png";
        }

        if (menuTabs.Items[1].Selected == true)
        {
            menuTabs.Items[1].ImageUrl = "~/Images/wit2_over.png";
            menuTabs.Items[0].ImageUrl = "~/Images/wit1.png";

        }
    }
  **//design code**
       <asp:Menu ID="menuTabs" CssClass="menuTabs" StaticMenuItemStyle-CssClass="tab" StaticSelectedStyle-CssClass="selectedTab"
            OnMenuItemClick="menuTabs_MenuItemClick" runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal"
            BackColor="#f4f4f4" BorderStyle="None" class="img-swap1">
            <StaticSelectedStyle CssClass="selectedTab"></StaticSelectedStyle>
            <StaticMenuItemStyle CssClass="tab"></StaticMenuItemStyle>
            <Items>
                <asp:MenuItem Text="" Value="0" Selected="true" ImageUrl="Images/wit1_over.png" />
                <asp:MenuItem Text="" Value="1" ImageUrl="Images/wit2.png" />
            </Items>
        </asp:Menu>


        <asp:MultiView ID="multiTabs" ActiveViewIndex="0" runat="server">
            <asp:View ID="view1" runat="server">
              </asp:View>
            <asp:View ID="view2" runat="server">
              </asp:View>
        </asp:MultiView>
```